# fortran call subroutine depending on kind value error

Tags: fortran

I want to call a subroutine depending on the kind value of the argument. I tried the following, but I get an error.

```
parameter, integer:: kind=4
integer(kind):: variable

if (kind==8) then
    call routine_kind8(variable)
elseif(kind==4) then
    call routine_kind4(variable)
endif
```

I get the following error:

```
call routine_kind8(variable)
                   1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'variable' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

The subroutine `routine_kind8` could be defined is defined as follows:

```
subroutine routine_kind8(variable)
implicit none
integer(8), intent(in):: variable

call api_write_data_to_file(variable)

end subroutine routine
```

where `api_write_data_to_file` is a function from an api which can accept any kind type. However, I can not dynamically define kind types in the argument list. Therefore it is necessary for me to call different versions of this routine, based on the kind type of the variable.
I can or more precisely don't want to call `api_write_data_to_file` directly. Instead I want to call it inside `routine_kind8`

Comment: Do you mean `parameter, integer` rather than `integer, parameter`?

Comment: @francescalus yes, it happens when I compile with `kind` having value 4. If `kind` would have value 8 it we be exactly the other way arround. `parameter, integer` or `integer, parameter` does not matter. I want to emphasize that define the kind type of the variable in the variable `kind`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a fairly recent compiler, you might look into *unlimited polymorphism* to achieve your goal. Then, you can even pass different types to the same subroutine:

```
module test_mod
contains
  subroutine print_type( input )
    class(*),intent(in)  :: input

    select type(input)
    type is (integer(kind=4))
      print *, "Got an integer of kind 4"
    type is (integer(kind=8))
      print *, "Got an integer of kind 8"
    type is (real)
      print *, "Got a real number"
    type is (complex)
      print *, "Got a complex number"
    end select
  end subroutine
end module

program test
use test_mod

  call print_type( 1_4 )
  call print_type( 1_8 )
  call print_type( 1. )
  call print_type( (1.,1.) )

end program
```

You can use the `select case` statement to further decide how to proceed and which further subroutines to call. Or, skip the `select case` statement alltogether and pass everything to `api_write_data_to_file` directly.

Alternatively you could create an `interface` block for `api_write_data_to_file()` in the same manner:

```
  interface api_write_data_to_file
    subroutine api_write_data_to_file(variable)
      class(*),intent(in)  :: variable
    end subroutine
  end interface
```

Then, you do not need a wrapper to call `api_write_data_to_file()`.

Comment: thank you, this is a really good suggestion. Unfortunetaly I am forced to use .f90, therefore I cannot use features from newer versions of Fortran.

Comment: @Skyy2010 The file extension `.f90` just indicates that the free form of Fortran source code is chosen... It does not indicate the feature set or supported Standard of the compiler. You could still try whether your compiler supports this construct. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using gfortran compiler. But it halso has to work with ifort compiler.

Comment: @Skyy2010 `gfortran` supports unlimited polymorphism starting with 4.8, `ifort` supports it even longer... The oldest working version I have of `ifort` is 11.1.046 (before the 2012 version) and it supports the test program. Just try the test program I gave with your compiler to make sure...

Comment: It really does work on both compilers and solves my problem in the best possible way ;) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An `if` construct with constant expression conditions is not the same thing as conditional compilation.  Dead code elimination also doesn't apply to ensure that only one of the blocks is processed.

What that means is that, when you have the declaration `integer(kind=4) variable` you do still have a line saying

```
call routine_kind8(variable)
```

which is expecting an `integer(kind=8)` argument.

You could use conditional compilation with a pre-processor, for example, but a far better approach could be to use generic resolution:

```
parameter, integer:: kind=4
integer(kind):: variable

call routine(variable)
```

where around the creation of `routine_kind4` and `routine_kind8` there has been something like

```
interface routine
  procedure routine_kind4    ! Defined at some point
  procedure routine_kind8
end interface
```